# Ruby script not running when Process.daemon is added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, daemon

I have the following simple script, which checks an email account and if there is new mail it forwards the email and sends an SMS. This happens as expected when the script is run without `Process.daemon`. When it is added, and email is received at the email account, nothing happens (nothing is forwarded and no SMS is sent) and there are no error messages in the console. Any suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "bundler/setup"
require "mailman"
require "twilio-ruby"

Mailman.config.pop3 = {
  :username => 'address@gmail.com',
  :password => 'password',
  :server   => 'pop.gmail.com',
  :port     => 995,
  :ssl      => true
}

Mailman.config.poll_interval = 60

Mailman::Application.run do  
  default do
    begin
      Ticket.receive_mail(message)
      MailForwarder.forwarded_email(message).deliver
      @account_sid = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
      @auth_token = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
      @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)
      @account = @client.account
      @sms = @account.sms.messages.create(
        :from => '+1111111111',
        :to => '+122222222',
        :body => message.subject
      )
      puts @sms
      puts "#{message.subject}"
    rescue Exception => e
      Mailman.logger.error "Exception occurred whle receiving message:\n#{message}"
      Mailman.logger.error [e, *e.backtrace].join("\n")
    end
  end
  Process.daemon
end
```

Comment: You say it "fails to work", but in what way exactly does it fail to work?

Comment: The script checks an email account and if there is new mail it forwards the email and sends an SMS, which happens when the script is run without `Process.daemon`. When it is added, and email is received at the email account, nothing is forwarded and no SMS is sent.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to set up your script as a daemon before you start up the mailman application.  I did a bit of testing, and it worked fine if I called Process.daemon before calling the Mailman::Application.run but it didn't work if I put it where you had it.

So I had it as:

```
....

Mailman.config.poll_interval = 15

Process.daemon

Mailman::Application.run do

 default do


 end

end
```